# Is it possible to define a list of const variable using WITH on ClickHouse server side instead of passing along with query request?

Tags: common-table-expression, clickhouse, with-statement

I have a use case where I need define two nested columns: column_uint32.name Array(String)，column_uint32.value Array(UInt32).

With the two columns I can store arbituary key/values.

This helps with the case that if I have more than 5000 dynamic columns, instead of define a wide table, I just need two column.

I have other optimizations/consideration to make the query efficient so performance is not a concern here.

But it makes the query cumbersome.

e.g. I want to `select cpu_util from t`.
I have to write: `select column_uint32.value[indexOf(column_uint32.name, 'cpu_util')] from t`.
It becomes worse when I write complicated query.
I am thinking of a way of pre-defining all the 5000 columns with "WITH" clause.

```
WITH cpu_util as column_uint32.value[indexOf(column_uint32.name, 'cpu_util')],
     mem_util as column_uint32.value[indexOf(column_uint32.name, 'mem_util')]
     .....
```

Then my query becomes as simple as `select cpu_util from t` again,.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you may try to use [ALIAS](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/statements/create/table/#alias) columns

```sql
create table ...
(

  column_uint32.name Array(String),
  column_uint32.value Array(UInt32),
  ....
  cpu_util AIAS column_uint32.value[indexOf(column_uint32.name, 'cpu_util')],
  mem_util AIAS column_uint32.value[indexOf(column_uint32.name, 'mem_util')]
)
```